# Multiple Tables React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to display multiple tables with individual data on each. No matter what I try I only manage to display the 3 tables but with all the same data. Would it be possible for someone to give an example of how to do so?

I've put the code back to displaying just the original set of data but showing the 3 tables.

[image: Tables shown]

Be a massive help if someone could show me how to add the data for the 2nd and 3rd table.

Thank you

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from "react-native";
import { Table, TableWrapper, Row, Cell } from "react-native-table-component";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default class ExampleFour extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableHead: ["Name", "Amount(£)", "Ref", "Payment"],
      tableData: [
        ["T. Walker", "870", "3", "d"],
        ["S. Weintraub", "650", "c", "d"],
        ["M. Clingan", "320", "3", "4"],
        ["S. Lucy", "1010", "c", "d"]
      ]
    };
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };
  _alertIndex(index) {
    Alert.alert(`Payment Sent`);
  }

  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    const element = (data, index) => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._alertIndex(index)}>
        <View style={styles.btn}>
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>button</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Title>Payments - Outgoing </Title>
        <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 1 }}>
          <Row
            data={state.tableHead}
            style={styles.head}
            textStyle={styles.text}
          />
          {state.tableData.map((rowData, index) => (
            <TableWrapper key={index} style={styles.row}>
              {rowData.map((cellData, cellIndex) => (
                <Cell
                  key={cellIndex}
                  data={cellIndex === 3 ? element(cellData, index) : cellData}
                  textStyle={styles.text}
                />
              ))}
            </TableWrapper>
          ))}
        </Table>
        <Title>Payments - Due </Title>
        <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 1 }}>
          <Row
            data={state.tableHead}
            style={styles.head}
            textStyle={styles.text}
          />
          {state.tableData.map((rowData, index) => (
            <TableWrapper key={index} style={styles.row}>
              {rowData.map((cellData, cellIndex) => (
                <Cell
                  key={cellIndex}
                  data={cellIndex === 3 ? element(cellData, index) : cellData}
                  textStyle={styles.text}
                />
              ))}
            </TableWrapper>
          ))}
        </Table>
        <Title>Payments - Overdue </Title>
        <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 1 }}>
          <Row
            data={state.tableHead}
            style={styles.head}
            textStyle={styles.text}
          />
          {state.tableData.map((rowData, index) => (
            <TableWrapper key={index} style={styles.row}>
              {rowData.map((cellData, cellIndex) => (
                <Cell
                  key={cellIndex}
                  data={cellIndex === 3 ? element(cellData, index) : cellData}
                  textStyle={styles.text}
                />
              ))}
            </TableWrapper>
          ))}
        </Table>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const Title = styled.Text`
  font-size= 16px;
  color: #b8bece;
  font-weight: 500;
  `;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
    paddingTop: 30,
    backgroundColor: "#f0f3f5"
  },
  head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: "#808B97" },
  text: { margin: 6 },
  row: { flexDirection: "row", backgroundColor: "white" },
  btn: {
    width: 58,
    height: 18,
    backgroundColor: "black",
    borderRadius: 2,
    alignSelf: "center"
  },
  btnText: { textAlign: "center", color: "#fff" }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the same data to render in all the three tables, in this case the data will be reflected same.

However if you use different value tableData1, tableData2, tableData3 in the below it will start reflecting unique data.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from "react-native";
import { Table, TableWrapper, Row, Cell } from "react-native-table-component";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default class ExampleFour extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableHead: ["Name", "Amount(£)", "Ref", "Payment"],
      tableData1: [
        ["T. Walker", "870", "3", "d"],
        ["S. Weintraub", "650", "c", "d"],
        ["M. Clingan", "320", "3", "4"],
        ["S. Lucy", "1010", "c", "d"]
      ],
      tableData2: [
        ["T. New", "870", "3", "d"],
        ["S. New", "650", "c", "d"],
        ["M. new", "320", "3", "4"],
        ["S. new", "1010", "c", "d"]
      ],
      tableData3: [
        ["T. New 2", "870", "3", "d"],
        ["S. New 2", "650", "c", "d"],
        ["M. new 2", "320", "3", "4"],
        ["S. new 2", "1010", "c", "d"]
      ],
    };
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };
  _alertIndex(index) {
    Alert.alert(`Payment Sent`);
  }

  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    const element = (data, index) => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._alertIndex(index)}>
        <View style={styles.btn}>
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>button</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Title>Payments - Outgoing </Title>
        <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 1 }}>
          <Row
            data={state.tableHead}
            style={styles.head}
            textStyle={styles.text}
          />
          {state.tableData1.map((rowData, index) => (
            <TableWrapper key={index} style={styles.row}>
              {rowData.map((cellData, cellIndex) => (
                <Cell
                  key={cellIndex}
                  data={cellIndex === 3 ? element(cellData, index) : cellData}
                  textStyle={styles.text}
                />
              ))}
            </TableWrapper>
          ))}
        </Table>
        <Title>Payments - Due </Title>
        <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 1 }}>
          <Row
            data={state.tableHead}
            style={styles.head}
            textStyle={styles.text}
          />
          {state.tableData2.map((rowData, index) => (
            <TableWrapper key={index} style={styles.row}>
              {rowData.map((cellData, cellIndex) => (
                <Cell
                  key={cellIndex}
                  data={cellIndex === 3 ? element(cellData, index) : cellData}
                  textStyle={styles.text}
                />
              ))}
            </TableWrapper>
          ))}
        </Table>
        <Title>Payments - Overdue </Title>
        <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 1 }}>
          <Row
            data={state.tableHead}
            style={styles.head}
            textStyle={styles.text}
          />
          {state.tableData3.map((rowData, index) => (
            <TableWrapper key={index} style={styles.row}>
              {rowData.map((cellData, cellIndex) => (
                <Cell
                  key={cellIndex}
                  data={cellIndex === 3 ? element(cellData, index) : cellData}
                  textStyle={styles.text}
                />
              ))}
            </TableWrapper>
          ))}
        </Table>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const Title = styled.Text`
  font-size= 16px;
  color: #b8bece;
  font-weight: 500;
  `;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
    paddingTop: 30,
    backgroundColor: "#f0f3f5"
  },
  head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: "#808B97" },
  text: { margin: 6 },
  row: { flexDirection: "row", backgroundColor: "white" },
  btn: {
    width: 58,
    height: 18,
    backgroundColor: "black",
    borderRadius: 2,
    alignSelf: "center"
  },
  btnText: { textAlign: "center", color: "#fff" }
});
```

Comment: Hmm I did try that I must have made an error when i set it up. Yours worked perfectly though thank you

Comment: Happy to help :)